# How to read this object in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have an object that shows like this:

```
Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection Object ( 
[heading:protected] => 
   Array ( 
       [0] => state 
       [1] => city 
       [2] => zipcode 
       ) 
[title:protected] => 
    Sheet1 [items:protected] => 
        Array ( 
            ...
            ) 
)
```

And I want the `[heading:protected]` section part. How do I get it?

I tried with  `json_encode`/`json_decode` but it did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a protected attribute, that's why you can't get the content directly, if you check the code [here](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/2.1/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Collections/RowCollection.php#L26), you'll see you can do with the getter method

```
$heading = $rowCollection->getHeading();
```